# Set the value of a textbox in a new table row using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a table in my JSP page. This table has rows which has some columns of textbox and select box. When I add a new row to this table and select "Unnamed" in the select box I want that the textbox value should become "N/A". I tried the below code but it does not work. Please help me.

```js
function unnamedNewStaffValidation(cb, value) {
  if (value == "Unnamed") {
    document.getElementById("postName_0").value = "N/A";
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input id="postName_0" name="newStaffWorkLoadList.postName" class="form-control input-sm" type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
      <select id="post_0" name="staffWorkLoadList[0].postType" class="form-control input-sm" onchange="unnamedNewStaffValidation(this.id, this.value)">
        <option value="">-Please Select-</option>
        <option value="Core">Core</option>
        <option value="Others">Others</option>
        <option value="Unnamed">Unnamed</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The javascript/jquery for adding a new row is as below:

```
$("#addStaff").click(function(){
        var tr=$("#our_table tr:eq(1)").clone();
        tr.find(":disabled").removeAttr("disabled");
        tr.find(":hidden").show();

        var index=1 + parseInt(($("#our_table tr:last").prev().find("input:eq(0)").attr('name')||'').replace(/[^\d]/g,''));

        if($("#our_table tr:last").prev().find("input:eq(0)").attr('disabled'))
        {
            index=index-1;
        }

        tr.find('input').each(function(){

            var name=$(this).attr('name').replace(/\[\d\]/,'['+index+']');
            $(this).attr('name',name);

        });

        tr.find('select').each(function(){

            var name=$(this).attr('name').replace(/\[\d\]/,'['+index+']');
            $(this).attr('name',name);

        });

        //$("#our_table").append(tr);
        tr.insertBefore($("#totalColumn"));

        bindTextCnltName(tr.find(".cnltName"));

        //show hide btn and link
        //showHideBtnNLink("add");          
    });
```

Comment: Note that the question has nothing to do with JSP, Java or jQuery so I removed those tags

Comment: Also, you have no `option` element in the `select` with a value of `N/A`. That's the only reason this doesn't work

Comment: Thx for removing tags, I do not want select with value of N/A. I want if I select "Unnamed" in the select box the textbox (id= postNme_0) value should become "N/A".

Comment: That makes no sense, you cannot set the value of a select to an arbitrary value - it needs to exist in one of the option elements

Comment: I am not setting value of select but the value of another textbox based on a value of select box.

Comment: Ok, I just saw your edit. Now the problem is that the `select` has no `option` with a value of `Unnamed`...

Comment: It has Unnamed.   <option value="Unnamed">Unnamed</option>

Comment: And it works... So I'm not sure what the issue is

Comment: The above code only work for existing rows in the table. I have a button to add more rows in table. So when I add a new row, this doesn't work,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id of the textbox input is not `post_0` but `postName_0`, so change the code like this:

```
function unnamedNewStaffValidation(cb, value) {
  if (value == "Unnamed") {
    document.getElementById("postName_0").value = "N/A";
  }
}
```

Here is working example where I removed the `display:none` and `disabled='disabled'` rules:

```js
$("#addStaff").click(function(){
  // Clone the first row
  var tr=$("#our_table tr:eq(1)").clone();

  // Get the index of the new row which is the count of all current rows
  var index = $("#our_table tr").length;
  
  tr.find('input').each(function(){
    var name=$(this).attr('id').replace(/\d/, index);
    $(this).attr('id',name);
  });

  tr.find('select').each(function(){
    var name=$(this).attr('id').replace(/\d/,index);
    $(this).attr('id',name);
  });

  tr.appendTo("#our_table");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function unnamedNewStaffValidation(cb, value) {
      // Get the number suffix from the current id
      var count = cb.split("_");
      count = count[count.length - 1];
     
      // Get the target input as the combination of 'postName_' and the count
      document.getElementById("postName_" + count).value = (value == "Unnamed") ? "N/A" : value;
    }
    </script>
    <table id="our_table">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input id="postName_0" name="newStaffWorkLoadList.postName" class="form-control input-sm"  type="text">
        </td>
        <td>
          <select id="post_0" name="staffWorkLoadList[0].postType"  class="form-control input-sm"  onchange="unnamedNewStaffValidation(this.id, this.value)">
            <option value="">-Please Select-</option>
            <option value="Core">Core</option>
            <option value="Others">Others</option>
            <option value="Unnamed">Unnamed</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input id="postName_1" name="newStaffWorkLoadList.postName" class="form-control input-sm"  type="text">
        </td>
        <td>
          <select id="post_1" name="staffWorkLoadList[0].postType"  class="form-control input-sm"  onchange="unnamedNewStaffValidation(this.id, this.value)">
            <option value="">-Please Select-</option>
            <option value="Core">Core</option>
            <option value="Others">Others</option>
            <option value="Unnamed">Unnamed</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>  
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input id="postName_2" name="newStaffWorkLoadList.postName" class="form-control input-sm"  type="text">
        </td>
        <td>
          <select id="post_2" name="staffWorkLoadList[0].postType"  class="form-control input-sm"  onchange="unnamedNewStaffValidation(this.id, this.value)">
            <option value="">-Please Select-</option>
            <option value="Core">Core</option>
            <option value="Others">Others</option>
            <option value="Unnamed">Unnamed</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>  
    </table>
<button id="addStaff">
  add Staff
</button>
```

Comment: Thx for your help, but the above code only work for existing rows in the table. I have a button to add more rows in table. So when I add a new row, this doesn't work, Please help.

Comment: Well, how does the newly added html look like? I can just assume that you generate unique id for the inputs and you do not use the same `post_0` and `postName_0`, so?

Comment: Ok let me edit my post to show how is the javascript for add staff

Comment: Can you please check now? I think I m making some mistake here maybe?

Comment: I've just edited my answer. I put there another two table rows where each row has  inputs with unique ids. And I've changed the code to dynamically create the id of the target input. Could you check it?

Comment: Yes I think I made a mistake in my naming or Id of new row, can u pls check my addStaff javascript above?

Comment: The way you are getting the index is little strange, why not just get the count of the rows in the table? And You should change the `id` attribute as well, not just the `name` attribute. Check my edit please